# spring boot with sitemesh

Tags: spring-boot, sitemesh

I'm using spring boot, and I would like to use sitemesh3 to my project.
I need to add the sitemesh filter, I create this class :

```
@Configuration
public class Initializer implements ServletContextInitializer{


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        //Sitemesh
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic sitemesh = servletContext.addFilter("sitemesh", new ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter());
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> sitemeshDispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
        sitemesh.addMappingForUrlPatterns(sitemeshDispatcherTypes, true, "*.jsp");



    }
}
```

I created the file `sitemesh3.xml` in *WEB-INF* directory but nothing happened, have I missed some configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServletContextInitializer`s aren't picked up with Spring Boot. Add the filter to your application configuration and wrap it in a `FilterRegistrationBean`.

See the Spring Boot [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-and-filters).